# Exchanging objects between processes Python

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

The following code checks whether a certain property is verified within a list of tetrahedra by means of processes.

**RUN METHOD**

```
def process(tetrahedrons, startOfWork, endOfWork, RelativeResult):
    print("Start of the process", mp.current_process().name)
    result = False
    for c in range(startOfWork,endOfWork):
        for j in range(c+1,len(tetrahedrons)):
            if tetrahedrons[c].IsInterpenetrated(tetrahedrons[j]) == 1:
                result = True
    print("Relative result = ",result, end="\n\n")
    RelativeResult.put(result)
```

**METHOD OF PARALLEL SEARCH**

```
def parallelInterpenetrationSearchWithProcess(self, tetrahedrons):
    
    '''
    parallel verification of the existence
                          of an interpenetration between tetrahedra
    '''
    time_start = datetime.datetime.now()

    N_CORE = mp.cpu_count()
    Workers = []
    QuantityForWorker = int(len(tetrahedrons) / N_CORE)
    Rest = len(tetrahedrons) % N_CORE
    StartWork = 0

    if QuantityForWorker == 0:
        iterations = Rest -1
    else:
        iterations = N_CORE

    for i in range(iterations):
        EndWork = StartWork + QuantityForWorker
        if i < Rest -1:
            EndWork = EndWork + 1
        IdWork = i
        Workers.append( mp.Process( target = process,
                                    args   = ( tetrahedrons,
                                               StartWork,
                                               EndWork,
                                               output
                                               )
                                    )
                        )
        Workers[IdWork].start()
        StartWork = EndWork

    for worker in Workers:
            worker.join()
            
    while not(RelativeResult.empty()):
        if RelativeResult.get():
            print( "Parallel search took %f seconds" %
                   ( timeelapsed( time_start ) )
                   )
            return True
    print( "Parallel search took %f seconds" %
           ( timeelapsed( time_start ) )
           )
    return False
```

It works for small size of the input array "*tetrahedrons*",however it gives me problems by failing miserably with higher dimensions of the latter. I think this happens because every time I go to create a process, it creates a copy in memory of all the current parameters that have been made available to it. You understand that copying an array of 168,000 elements for 4,5,6 or 8 times is not a good thing to see. **So I'm looking for a way to share this array among all processes at my disposal.** I have seen various methodologies that can be exploited by the help of a shared memory through *`multiprocessing.sharedctypes.RawArray`*, using a `multiprocessing.Queue()`-instance, but I couldn't get anything good out of it.

---

To conclude:

**How** can I share an array so that it can be read by different processes without the latter having to create their own instance locally?

If you don't understand, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Honestly, this is the end of the line as far as Python goes. If you wish to optimize on this level you  need to use a lower level language. What you want is multi-threading (which explicitly shares memory), which does not give performance benefits in Python, but does in other languages.

Comment: I thought thats what `multiprocessing.Manager()` is used for?

Comment: @orlp I opted in fact with the use of point processes because I had become aware of the limitations of python in the use of threads. I tried to use 'multiprocessing.Manager ()', but it gives me the following error 'RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while pickling an object'. I think the problem is due to the amount of input used.